# Компьютерный анализ текста

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вопрос для курсовой работы нужно создать систему, которая выявляет экономические события (крупные сделки,международные сделки и так далее). Выделяет участников событий и по возможности сумму сделки.

Как я понял, тема относится к компьютерной лингвистике - к обработке, анализу и синтезу текста. Хотелось бы получить несколько мудрых советов от более опытных людей, список литературы имеется, но я не могу толком решить, какой метод и алгоритм наиболее эффективен для  решения поставленной задачи.

Прошу вас не пишите что это задание можно сделать легко с помощью регулярных выражении или конечных автоматов (это прошлый век, так делали 40 лет назад). Хотелось бы узнать про конкретные алгоритмы, с помощью которых можно решить эту задачу, но если скинете список литературы, то это тоже не будет лишним, заранее спасибо.

Comment: У вас же уже есть список литературы, зачем вам еще один? :)

Comment: Где вы учите компьютерную лингвистику? В университете? Если уж там ничего не дают, то что Вам скажет выпускник ПТУ из какого-нибудь захолустья, который задачи по регулярным выражениям решает с помощью этого сайта, а о конечных автоматах никогда и не слышал. Это Вы могли бы поделиться тут академическими знаниями.

Comment: У меня в университете не преподавали компьютерную лингвистку(ну по крайней мере пока) я просто читал про нее.Прошу прощения возможно мой вопрос вызвал какое-то негодование со стороны людей ,я просто хотел получить совет вот и все.